# Add two dates times together in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to add two dates:

```
date start Fri Apr 26 2013 16:08:03 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)
+  
date periode Fri Apr 26 2013 00:10:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)
```

I used this code:

```
var periode=$("#dure").val();
var start = $("#start").val()
var end =$("#end").val();

var dateStart= new Date(start);
console.log('start');
console.log(dateStart);

var date=dateStart.format('yyyy-mm-dd'); 
per=date+' '+periode;
var datePeriode= new Date(per);

console.log('datePeriode');
console.log(datePeriode);
var dateEnd= dateStart.getTime()+datePeriode.getTime();
console.log('dateEnd');
console.log(dateEnd);
```

In my JavaScript console, I get:

```
dateDebut
Fri Apr 26 2013 16:33:11 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)
datePeriode
Fri Apr 26 2013 00:15:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)
dateEnd
2733922091000
```

How can I fix that?  Am I missing something?

Comment: What does it mean to add two dates? What date is "April 26 + April 26"? A date isn't the same thing as a time period.

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense. You add a time period to a date (a specific instance in time). What do you expect to get when you add two dates?

Comment: I see so how can i add 16:33:11 with periode 00:15:00?

Comment: @Takwach You want to add 15 minutes to an existing time?

Comment: yes i select 5 minutes or 10,15.... and add the periode with the date start

Comment: _"What do you expect to get when you add two dates?"_ @VivinPaliath, the double

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to add a time period to a date, you basically have to convert both of them into milliseconds.

```
var date = new Date();
var dateMillis = date.getTime();

//JavaScript doesn't have a "time period" object, so I'm assuming you get it as a string
var timePeriod = "00:15:00"; //I assume this is 15 minutes, so the format is HH:MM:SS

var parts = timePeriod.split(/:/);
var timePeriodMillis = (parseInt(parts[0], 10) * 60 * 60 * 1000) +
                       (parseInt(parts[1], 10) * 60 * 1000) + 
                       (parseInt(parts[2], 10) * 1000);

var newDate = new Date();
newDate.setTime(dateMillis + timePeriodMillis);

console.log(date); //eg: Fri Apr 26 2013 08:52:50 GMT-0700 (MST)
console.log(newDate); //eg: Fri Apr 26 2013 09:07:50 GMT-0700 (MST)
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert datePeriod to milliseconds instead of making it into a date object for your addition.

You need to convert the sum to a date.  `getTime()` is in milliseconds since 1-1-1970.  So you want to do.

```
var ending = new Date();
ending.setTime(dateEnd);
console.log(ending);
```

`setTime` will set the date properly for you.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setTime

Comment: Don't use a `Date` for datePeriode, convert it to milliseconds before adding it.