# Javascript Time. Add +1 to current time

Tags: javascript, time, timer

Hi I want my timer to continue from the current time each second. Keeping the same time format. I just added a simple code to check.

Code

```
<div id="output"></div>
<script>
    const output = document.querySelector("#output");
    let time = "12:48:39"
    let seconds = 0;

    function timer() {
        seconds++;
        let hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
        // Get minutes
        let minutes = Math.floor((seconds - hours * 3600) / 60);
        // Get seconds
        let secs = Math.floor(seconds % 60);

        if (hours < 10) {
            hours = `0${hours}`;
        }
        if (minutes < 10) {
            minutes = `0${minutes}`;
        }
        if (secs < 10) {
            secs = `0${secs}`;
        }
        return `${hours}:${minutes}:${secs}`;
    }
    setInterval(() => {
        output.innerHTML = parseInt(time + timer())
    }, 1000)
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working solution.

You had to split your string that represents time, so you can count the amount of seconds that you actually had.

**Note:** *I've  used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9640384/18099076) as help for transitioning from HH:MM:SS to numbers.*

And, in the end, you just need to get the `timer()` string, there is no need to write both time and the return element of timer function.

```html
<div id="output"></div>
<script>
    const output = document.querySelector("#output");
    let time = "12:48:39"
    let a = time.split(':');
    let seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]); ;
    let ti = "";
    function timer() {
        seconds++;
        let hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
        // Get minutes
        let minutes = Math.floor((seconds - hours * 3600) / 60);
        // Get seconds
        let secs = Math.floor(seconds % 60);
        
        if (hours < 10) {
            hours = `0${hours}`;
        }
        if (minutes < 10) {
            minutes = `0${minutes}`;
        }
        if (secs < 10) {
            secs = `0${secs}`;
        }
        ti = `${hours}:${minutes}:${secs}`;
        return ti;
    }
    setInterval(() => {
        output.innerHTML = timer();
    }, 1000)
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're asking here... why the code isn't working?

### Explanation:

First of all I'm pretty sure at least *part of the issue* is the fact that `time` and the output of `timer()` are both **strings** which you are concatenating together and then attempting to parse as **numbers**.

When you do `time + timer()` it's the same as doing `"12:48:39" + timer()` and for example if the output of timer is 0:01:12 (seconds = 72) then that's the same as doing:

```js
"12:48:39" + "0:01:12"
```

Which will just output `"12:48:390:01:12"` because it will concatenate the two strings.

When you then pass that into `parseInt()`, you are essentially doing:

```js
parseInt("12:48:390:01:12")
```

`parseInt()` won't know what to do with that since it's not simple number so it will just parse the beginning and throw away the rest; it will return `12`, the first number.

#### Solution:

So... if your goal is to add two times I recommend using `Date` which allows you to store dates and times properly. See: [Add two dates times together in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240262/add-two-dates-times-together-in-javascript)

Hope this helps :)